# angularFire unable to $add data to firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am using angularFire and trying to save data from a form to firebase with $add. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The console logs all work, I am able to retrieve the data in the console. Sorry for all of the code... I wanted to be sure I provided all the material needed.

app.js:

```
    var creativeBillingApp = angular.module('creativeBillingApp', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

    creativeBillingApp.constant('FIREBASE_URI', "https://XXXX.firebaseIO.com/");

    creativeBillingApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'groupsService', function( $scope,  groupsService, $firebase ) {

    console.log('Works')


    $scope.newGroup = {
     name: '',
     status: ''

    };

   $scope.addGroup = function(newGroup){

   console.log(newGroup);

groupsService.addGroup();
  $scope.newGroup = {
    name: '',
    status: ''

  };
};
 $scope.updateGroup = function (id) {
   groupsService.updateGroup(id);
 };

 $scope.removeGroup = function(id) {
   groupsService.removeGroup(id);
 };
}]);




creativeBillingApp.factory('groupsService', ['$firebase', 'FIREBASE_URI',
  function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URI) {
    'use strict';
    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI);
    return $firebase(ref).$asArray();

var groups = $firebase(ref).$asArray();

var getGroups = function(){
  return groups;
};

var addGroup = function (newGroup) {
  console.log(newGroup)
  groups.$add(newGroup);
};

var updateGroup = function (id){
  groups.$save(id);
};

var removeGroup = function (id) {
  groups.$remove(id);
};
return {
  getGroups: getGroups,
  addGroup: addGroup,
  updateGroup: updateGroup,
  removeGroup: removeGroup,
}

}]);
```

index.html:

```
         <form role="form" ng-submit="addGroup(newGroup)">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="groupName">Group Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="groupName" ng-model="newGroup.name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="groupStatus">Group Status</label>
              <select class="form-control" ng-model="newGroup.status">
                <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
                <option value="active">Active</option>
              </select>
            </div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Scope.$scope.addGroup (http://localhost:9000/scripts/app.js:35:19)
```

and the app.js line 35 is in reference to groupsService.addGroup(); from the app.js code given above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, you are returning in your service after you create your `$FirebaseArray`. You are also creating another `$FirebaseArray` after that.

```
return $firebase(ref).$asArray();
```

Remove that return statement. That is causing your service to return early and none of the attached methods will apply to your service.

In `groupService.addGroup()` you are calling push, which is not a function on `$asArray`. You need to call `.$add()`. The `newGroup` argument is also not being passed in the controller.

The `$.push` method is available on the base of the `$firebase` binding. When you using a `$FirebaseArray` the `$add` method pushes a new record into Firebase.

[See the docs for more info](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray-addnewdata).

**[Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/aW7To6tNG205U0ddRzLs?p=preview)**

```
var addGroup = function (newGroup) {
  console.log(newGroup)
  groups.$add(newGroup);
};
```

Then in your controller you can simply call:

```
$scope.addGroup = function(newGroup){
  groupsService.addGroup(newGroup);

  $scope.newGroup = {
    name: '',
    status: ''
  };
};
```

Comment: thank you for responding! I have tried $add and it is giving me the same error in the console.

Comment: You are returning from your service at the very top. Remove that line. I have updated the answer.

Comment: THANKS! That got rid of the error however, now it is returning undefined in the console when I console.log(newGroup) from under the var addGroup.

Comment: There's too much that could be wrong there. Can you post an example in JSBin or a Plnker?

Comment: I've never made one of these. http://plnkr.co/edit/9ydzjIlDCETqCk8Vsu01?p=preview

Comment: It's not working. You need to setup the ng-app and controller directives.

Comment: Sorry, I just added those!

Comment: You also need to include the script references for Firebase, Angular, and AngularFire. I added those and made a new plunker. The problem is the same from before, you weren't passing newGroup to the `groupsService.addGroup()` function. http://plnkr.co/edit/aW7To6tNG205U0ddRzLs?p=preview

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! it's such a relief to have it working, you are the greatest.